# Unity error while trying to send data to an online post api

Tags: api, unity-game-engine, post

I'am trying to make a post api work on unity with a dummy post api online before working on a real post api that is part of my internship's project.
I dont really know why the post api is not working on unity despite that i entered the right arguments and it works on postman.
i have commented my code a little bit that might help.

```
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine; 
using UnityEngine.UI; 
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class API: MonoBehaviour {

  private const string URL = "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/create";
  public Text responseText;

  public void Request() {

   WWWForm FORM = new WWWForm();

   FORM.AddField("name", "tarek");
   FORM.AddField("salary", "9001");
   FORM.AddField("age", "26");
   byte[] rawFormData = FORM.data;

   WWW request = new WWW(URL, rawFormData);
   StartCoroutine(Reponse(request));
   Debug.Log("text :" + request.text);

  }

  private IEnumerator Reponse(WWW req) {
   yield
   return new WaitForSeconds(2.0 f);
   yield
   return req;
   responseText.text = req.text;
   Debug.Log("end : " + req.text);

  }
```

Comment: Before anything else I think that you should avoid WWW and use UnityWebRequest instead.
WWW is obsolete and it will be removed soon from Unity.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the info.Infact i have just resolved the problem it was just the dummy api that i have used that wasn't working, and i just came to know that the WWW that i am using in the moment is about to be rmoved from unity. thank you very much sir!